# Is ‘in its own turn’ used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> The relation between freedom and democracy is not one-sided: democracy
> does require freedom, but contributes, **in its own turn**, to
> freedom as well.

Here I’ve used  ‘in its own turn’ to emphasize two-sidedness in the relationship between democracy and freedom. Yes I’ve used ‘but’ and ‘as well’ which might convey the two-sidedness of the relationship. But I wanted to emphasize that using ‘in its own turn’. Is that phrase used correctly here?

I know that ‘in turn’ imply some sequence. But I am not sure that ‘in its turn’ means exactly the same. Funny enough, I couldn’t find the latter in dictionaries.

Comment: In formal writing "for sure" is not recommended.

Comment: require freedom for sure, sounds very informal. And I would use: in turn, and not in its own turn. You can use" **does** require freedom.

Comment: You seem to have left out the word _freedom_ before the word _contributes_. Otherwise you are saying that democracy contributes to democratization.

Comment: @TonyK has uncovered an issue. One correction: *... but contributes, in turn, to freedom*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Oh yes, you're right! My 'correction' was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

***In one's turn*** is an idiomatic rhetorical expression. OED explains that

> ***in one's turn*** means *in one's due order in the series*. (Often *in turn* is also used ***rhetorically*** like *in one's turn* ***to indicate an act duly or naturally following a similar act on the part of another,*** but without the notion of pre-arranged succession.)

The bold part of the definition refers to your case. It involves a certain symmetry.

As for ***own***, it does not bring new information, but only emphasises. [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22own%22&biw=1536&bih=722&sxsrf=ALiCzsaxInftCN2gzgCRjWZDDK37iDo3dg%3A1659365507134&ei=g-jnYrHoB9SagQb08YDACA&ved=0ahUKEwjxteuc8qX5AhVUTcAKHfQ4AIgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22own%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBQgAEJECMgcIABDJAxBDMgoILhCxAxDUAhBDMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgQIABBDMgQIABADOgcIABBHELADOgcIIxCuAhAnOgQIABAKOgcIABDJAxAKOgUIABCABDoICAAQgAQQyQM6CggAEIAEEIcCEBRKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ3ApYhBtgzS5oAXABeACAAakBiAGMDZIBBDE1LjOYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) says that *own* is

> used with a possessive ***to emphasize*** that someone or something belongs or relates to the person or thing mentioned.

As far as your sentence is concerned, I think it is better to omit ***own***, since over-emphasising is never the strong point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

> (SOED) **in turn(s)** In due order of succession; successively, alternately.

> (SOED) **in one's turn** When one's turn or opportunity comes

**In one's own turn**          I can't find a reference confirming theis phrase is a variant of the preceding, but I suspect that "own" does nothing more than to add emphasis.

In fact, it seems better to use "in its (own) turn", as it is clear that there is no process of succession or of alternance in the interaction between democracy and freedom.